# node db migration options with es6 support?

Tags: node.js, database-migration, ecmascript-6

I cannot find any migration tool in node for db-migrations with es6 support.

I tried to use --harmony flag with node-migrate, but could not make it work.

Is it possible or should I just stick with non-es6 migration tools?

Comment: What do you need ES6 for when doing db migration? Which ES6 features are lacking from currently available tools?

Comment: @Bergi Hello, thx for the reply. I am want to use import, export and let keywords mainly

Comment: Which tool are you currently using? You can always use ES6 syntax yourself (and import ES5 modules) by using a transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

Try [node-db-migration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-db-migration)

Example with es6:

```
import * as sqlite3 from 'sqlite3';
import {CommandsRunner, SQLite3Driver} from 'node-db-migration';

async function run() {
    const db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');
    const migrations = new CommandsRunner({
        driver: new SQLite3Driver(db),
        directoryWithScripts: __dirname + '/diff',
    });
    await migrations.run('migrate')
    console.log("this will print after migrations are finished");
}
run();
```